# Attempt to extract Twitter data from London location

Tags: python, twitter, ipython, twitter-streaming-api

very new to this but I need twitter data from the area of London from the streaming api service

This is the code i'm running

```
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener

class MyListener(StreamListener):

def on_data(self, data):
    try:
        with open('london.json', 'a') as f:
            f.write(data)
            return True
    except BaseException as e:
        print("Error on_data: %s" % str(e))
    return True

def on_error(self, status):
    print(status)
    return True

twitter_stream = Stream(auth, MyListener())
twitter_stream.filter(locations=['0.28,51.23,0.25,51.68'])
```

This is the error I keep getting

```
TweepError: Wrong number of locations points, it has to be a multiple of 4
```

I may be getting the bounding box wrong but am unsure how to find it for London??

Thanks

Comment: Try to put them in like this
`locations=[0.28,51.23,0.25,51.68]`

Comment: @KRONWALLED this has given me the 406 error - does this mean my bounded box is wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Hmm your bounding box seems fine.
Could you show us your auth mechanism. Just clear your user, pass and put placeholders in it.

Comment: Bounding box looks wrong. Try `locations=[0.25,51.23,0.28,51.68]`.